# Is it likely that an alkyd varnish contains lead?

Tags: lead, alkyd

To be more precise, an alkyde varnish which is commercialized in Morocco : https://www.atlaspeintures.ma/RECHERCHES/FicheExport.php?Produit=47
Do you think there is a possibility that it contains a lead-based siccative ?

Comment: you are asking two different questions ... which one do you want answered?

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear you are right. I want to know if an alkyd varnish is susceptible to contain lead used as siccative (since there is no clear way to know if it is the case for the link I gave).

Comment: Have you looked at the ingredient list on the can or the manufacturer's web site? Have you looked for a Material Data Safety Sheet (or similar)? Have you contacted the manufacturer to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Most responsible countries know the hazards of using lead that my become air born causing health issues if inhaled. The surest way to know is to read the label of ingredients on the container  or any suggested warnings from the manufacturer.

Most varnishes are made with resins and some kind of solvent. Inhaling the dust when sanding or the vapor while applying it can cause health problems related mostly in the lungs. Ingesting lead is much more detrimental especially to children where it effects brain function.

Answer (score 0):

Although lead paint is banned in Morocco, a recent survey found some paint products still contain hazardous amounts of lead.

https://ipen.org/sites/default/files/documents/ipen-morocco-lead-report%20final.pdf